# Markov chain and transition matrix

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

We consider a Markov chain taking values in $E$ and having a transition matrix $(p(x,y))_{x,y \in E}.$ Let $F \subset E$ be finite and $T:=\inf \{ n \in \mathbb{N}^*,X_n \in F\}.$ We want to find $P_x(X_T=y)$ in term of $p(x,y),$ in other words, to prove that $$\forall x,y \in E,P_x(X_T=y)=p(x,y)1_F(y)+\sum_{u \in F^c}p(x,u)P_u(X_T=y)$$

I was wondering how to prove this identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is very similar to previous ones,  and is included at the OP's request. We assume the chain is recurrent, so $T<\infty$ almost surely.

When $y \notin F$, both sides of the identity vanish, so we may take $y \in F$. Write out the tower property of conditional expectation:

$$P_x(X_T = y) = E[P_x(X_T = y|X_1)]=\sum_{u \in E}p(x, u)P_x(X_T = y \mid X_1 = u).$$
Now $h(u)=P_x(X_T = y \mid X_1 = u)$ equals $p(x,y)$ if $u=y$, while $h(u)=0$ if $u \in F\setminus{y}$. Finally, if $u \notin F$ then the Markov property at time $1$ gives
$h(u)=P_u(X_T = y)$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that $T < \infty$ a.s.. If not, then you have to define $X_{\infty}$.

Then
$$P_x(X_T = y) = \sum_{u \in E}p(x, u)P_x(X_T = y \mid X_1 = u).$$
Use the Markov property to write down a piecewise formula for $f(u) = P_x(X_T = y \mid X_1 = u)$. After plugging the formula into the summation, you get the summation you wrote.